# Nodemailer.js Data URI attachment

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send a DataURI attachment via nodemailer

This is my code:

```
    var mailOptions = {
    from: 'Testing' <test@test.com>', 
    to: recipient,
    bcc: 'test2@test.com',
    subject: 'Testing Attachment functionality', 
    attachments: [
        {
        filename: 'attachment',
        filePath: dataURI
        },
        ],
    html: '<p> Check the attachment</p>'
    }
```

I receive a mail with the attachment, but it is a blank file the size of some bytes. For example, if I send the DataURI of a PNG file, I get a DAT file in my mailbox.

Has anybody encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my code was wrong. I updated to the most recent version of Nodemailer (v1+) and used the following code:

```
attachments: [
        {
            path: dataURI                
        }
        ]
```